# How to Show data From Database

Tags: mysql

```
select tblposts.id as pid,
        tblposts.PostTitle as posttitle,
        tblposts.PostImage,
        tblcategory.CategoryName as category,
        tblcategory.id as cid,
        tblsubcategory.Subcategory as subcategory,
        tblposts.PostDetails as postdetails,
        tblposts.PostingDate as postingdate,
        tblposts.PostUrl as url 
from tblposts 
    left join tblcategory on tblcategory.id=13 
    left join tblsubcategory on tblsubcategory.SubCategoryId=tblposts.SubCategoryId 
where tblposts.Is_Active=1 
order by tblposts.id DESC
```

how can i show data from tblcategory where ID = 13

Comment: Just put your condition in where clause instead of left join condition.

Comment: `left join tblcategory on tblcategory.id = tblposts.category_id AND tblcategory.id=13` or put it in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

You have to change a bit your query:

```
from tblposts 
    left join tblcategory on <here is the JOIN condition> 
    left join tblsubcategory on tblsubcategory.SubCategoryId=tblposts.SubCategoryId 
where tblposts.Is_Active=1 and tblcategory.id=13  //<-Here goes the filter condition 
order by tblposts.id DESC
```

You haven't specified your database structure so in the <> part you have to write the condition that join the two tables